# Jenkins - Release management integration

Tags: jenkins, ms-release-management

we run builds on Jenkins and would like to deploy artifacts using a Microsoft release management (TFS 2017.2). So far seems easy, but the problem is that we use folders within the Jenkins so the Release Management cannot see all jobs and see only Jenkins folders. Did anyone handled such an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After involving Microsoft support, I got this answer:

> The capability to link jobs organized in folders is not included in
>   TFS 2017. It is amongst the latest of the features on VSTS and would
>   be available in the next update to TFS 2018.